# Moving godaddy VPS Webserver to AWS?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, backend, serverless, godaddy-api

Is it possible to move my VPS godaddy webserver that supports my iOS mobile social media application to AWS? AWS Lambda? If the database is copied over.. how much additional work will it take to get my aws database up and running on aws? AWS Lambda seems to be able to scale infrastructure automatically.. but will I need to change anything or run additional scripts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to copy/paste your VPS to AWS.

AWS Lambda is a serverless infrastructure, I can say it is completely different to work with Lambda and an ordinary VPS machine.
In Lambda, you execute "jobs", I mean, you send your script to be processed and get its return, you don't know where it is executed, and doesn't matter at all in fact.

However, you must adapt your backend to work in this infra, adapt scripts do be Lambda compliant etc.

Regarding database, it depends on its size, but I can say it would be the simplest task for you to accomplish, you can export from one side and import from another.
You can have a look on AWS CLI that can be helpful in this task.

For your compute server, I'm afraid you will have a fresh install and then copy and configure your services and API's.

Good luck

Comment: Great thank you. So I want to move my database to aws.. what aws service do you recommend? I am looking for an easy way to scale my social media app.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends of what DB you use, if relational db, have a look on `RDS` if non relational, DynamoDB or you get an `EC2` instance and set up your own db instance